# статическая переменная в классе

Tags: c++

Для чего нам нужно еще раз объявлять статическую переменную вне класса, указывать область видимости, если я уже в классе определил ее как статическую(`static int a`):

```
int shared::a
```

?

Класс:

```
class shared
{
    static int a;
};
```

Comment: Внутри классы вы ее объявили, а вот определили как раз вне класса.

Comment: В определении класса Вы написали объявление статической переменной без определения. Соответственно, необходимо определение в какой-либо единице трансляции.

Comment: разве я ее опять не обьявляю: `int a`?

Comment: Нет, объявили ее только один раз - внутри класса.

Comment: `int shared::a` - это разве определение??

Comment: Да, это определение. Определение легко отличить, так как в определении производится инициализация. Например написать `int shared::a = 5;` можно, а в теле класса `static int a = 5;` нельзя. Хотя такое ограничение было частично снято в новых стандартах, которые в некоторых случаях разрешают определение в теле класса.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В классе у вас располагается *объявление* статического члена класса, а не *определение*. *Определение* такой переменной вы делаете именно за пределами класса как `int shared::a;`.

"Для чего" это делается... Это делается, в частности, для того, чтобы вы могли указать реализации:

1. В каком порядке вы хотите инициализировать этот статический член класса, если ему нужна динамическая инициализация. Динамическая инициализация в каждой единице трансляции делается в порядке следования определений объектов, сверху-вниз. То есть то, в каком конкретном месте вы поместите определение статического члена класса, может влиять на его инициализацию.

   (В вашем случае - просто `int` - динамической инициализации нет, поэтому к вашему конкретному примеру это соображение не применимо.)
2. В какой единице трансляции (в каком объектном файле) вы хотите разместить определение этого статического члена класса, т.е. из какого объектного файла оно будет экспортироваться в качестве внешнего символа.

Если для вас в вашем конкретном случае эти вопросы не имеют никакого значения, то, начиная с С++17, вы можете объявить ваш член класса как `inline`

```
class shared
{
    static inline int a;
};
```

и никакого дополнительного определения не понадобится. Реализация в такой ситуации сама по своему усмотрению куда-то "пристроит" определение вашей переменной.

Answer (score 3):

А давайте представим, что это и есть - как вы хотите - определение переменной. Т.е. при таком тексте создается одна переменная *класса*. Не привязанная к объекту.

А теперь это объявление класса включено в N... нет, это мало... в M :) разных .cpp-файлов. И в каждом файле, получается, создается одна и та же переменная, с глобальной областью видимости.

Что делать линковщику? Если у него куча одноименных объектов?
Выбрать один? Какой именно?
Оставить все? И что тогда? В одном файле присваиваем 5, в другом - 10, в третьем читаем... что именно читаем?

Это так, краткое обоснование...

Comment: про объекты не совсем понял

Comment: я понял это так: поскольку определение класса-это просто шаблон, то при обьявлении членов класса ,память для них не выделяется(при чем только для статических), поэтому их нужно определять ,разрешая область видимости для класса

Comment: почему мы обычные члены класса не определяем?

Comment: @ArtemAleksandrovich Обычные определяются как часть экземпляра класса при каждом создании такого экземпляра.

Comment: @VTT вам отлично пояснил. В этом и есть отличие переменной класса (см. - я даже выделил это слово курсивом в ответе) от переменной экземпляра. Переменная экземпляра без экземпляра не существует - в отличие от переменной класса...