# Загрузка из std::map в шаблон

Tags: c++

Сделал частитчно менеджер загрузки спрайтов и моделей 3d. Загружается через `load_manager`. Вот так.

```
Sprite *sp = load_manager<Sprite>::getModel ( "schar_00" );
```

А вот код класс load_manager.

```
#include "object.h"
#include "model.h"
#include "sprite.h"
#include <map>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
class load_manager {
        private:
                static std::map <std::string,Object *> map;
        public:
                static T *getModel ( const char *s ) {
                        std::string path ( s );
                        T *view = map [ path ];
                        if ( view ) return view;
                        view->read_file ( s );
                        map [ path ] = view;
                        return view;
                }
};
```

Так как я создал `std::map < object * >`, то хотел бы, чтобы `T *view = map [ path ]` работала. Почему не может быть преобразована, если Sprite наследуется от Object? Как мне решить эту проблему?
Сделал преобразование, теперь ошибки такие.

```
/tmp/ccyZsl4K.o: In function `load_manager<Sprite>::getModel(char const*)':
/home/cf/projects/editor/./src/menu/../engine/load_manager.h:14: undefined reference to `load_manager<Sprite>::map[abi:cxx11]'
/home/cf/projects/editor/./src/menu/../engine/load_manager.h:18: undefined reference to `load_manager<Sprite>::map[abi:cxx11]'
```

Что указывает на строки где было преобразование.

Comment: Может вместо T *view написать Object *view?

Comment: А, нет. не так.

Comment: Не понял. Если `typename T` - это шаблонный параметр всего класса, то почему не хранить в мапе `T *`? Или шаблоном должен быть метод?

Comment: У меня два вида моделей, спрайт и obj объект. в map надо какой-то средний между ними засунуть. Чтобы можно было загрузить либо спрайт, либо модельку. Вроде шаблон это класс.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat надеюсь ты получил сообщение.

Comment: Специализацию? А сработает как надо? Ну чтобы логика программы была такой как у меня сейчас?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan я тебе выше написал.

Comment: @AnT блин, ant, что мне делать? Как правильно написать?

Comment: @AnT если в map есть объект, то он загрузиться в view. А ну да, щас исправлю, но всё равно в преобразовании не работает, там где надо присвоить из map в T *view.

Comment: Из того, что "Sprite наследуется от Object" следует, что первое можно неявно преобразовывать ко второму. Обратное же преобразование неявно выполняться не будет. С чего бы это вдруг? Также не ясно, что у вас там делается с указателем view. Зачем вы вызываете методы через нулевой указатель? И никакие вызовы методов не смогут сделать нулевой указатель ненулевым.

Comment: Сделал преобразования, теперь ошибки такие.

Comment: @AnT я подправил тему вопроса и добавил новую ошибку.

Comment: Тут вопросов много.  Не думаю, что вам нужен шаблонный класс вообше. И, если  функция возвращает  Object* то вы не сможете это присвоить указателью производного класса(можно наоборот).

Comment: Ну так а кто определение статического члена делать-то будет? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/773697/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5

Answer (score 1):

Так как   `load_manager`  содержит  и работает с конкретными типами,  то сделать его шаблонным не имеет никакого смысла. Его статический член  `map` является таблицей, для которого  `mapped_type` есть `Object*`,  и он может содержать и адреса своих производных классов, так что при инициализации вы можете туда записать и `Sprite*`, но вы не можете без явного преобразования присвоить указателью `Sprite*` указатель на `Object`, но наоборот можно. Вы могли бы написать так:

```
class load_manager {
private:
    static std::map <std::string, Object*> map;
public:
    static Object* getModel(const char* s) {
        std::string path(s);        
        if (!map[path])
           map[path]->read_file(s);
        return map[path];
    }
};
```

И...

```
Object* sp = load_manager::getModel("schar_00");
```

Comment: Ваш вариант не правильный. Если Object не знает о sprite, то как он будет загружать файл, как загружает спрайт.

Comment: xverizex,  обьект построен на основе своего базового класса, и к нему можно обращаться и  посредством указаелья на базовый класс, и не  нужно, чтобы базовый класс знал что нибудь о нем.  Как вы можете  оценить мой ответ, если вы сами не знаете  что  к чему?...

Comment: Ну вот у Object чисто виртуальные функции, типа read_file. Как я буду использовать функционал sprite по загрузку файла read_file, если sprite нигде не указан. Чтобы пользоваться read_file, нужно чтобы sprite был хотябы на этапе записи в std::map.

Comment: У вас map статический, и там должны быть записаны все данные, которые вам нужны. Если   функция предназначена только для одного конкретного типа, то вы должны написать отдельно эту функцию или  класс имеющую эту функцию или  написать ее только для фул специализации  шаблона.  Одним словом функция должна вызываться только для  sprite...

Comment: хорошо, спасибо.